# libiconv error when using twitteR package on R

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, libiconv

I was hard-pressed to find help on Stack Overflow with the issue I was having with the twitteR package on R. To make this simpler, I'll show you exactly what I entered:

```
reqURL<-"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL<-"http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL<-"http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
cKey="{my consumer key}"
cSecret="{my consumer secret}"
oKey="{my oauth key}"
oSecret="{my oauth secret}"
credentials<-OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=cKey,consumerSecret=cSecret,oauthKey=oKey,oauthSecret=oSecret, requestURL=reqURL,authURL=authURL)
credentials$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")
```

The console then responds

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
http://api.twitter.com/oauth /authorize?oauth_token=aMog9rDmJTphmNv0wnkN2ELtVDl20npVq7Vzv4L0IA
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:  {PIN entered here}
libidn: warning: libiconv not installed, cannot convert data to UTF-8
libidn: warning: libiconv not installed, cannot convert data to UTF-8
libidn: warning: libiconv not installed, cannot convert data to UTF-8
libidn: warning: libiconv not installed, cannot convert data to UTF-8
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Could not resolve host: xn--tmb; No data record of requested type
```

Looking up the warning beginning with "libidn" I was wondering if there was an underlying problem with the package or with my own computer, since I could only find responses to that error on forums for things way beyond my technical purview. I'm running on Windows Vista 32-bit, and I have R-2.14.1.

Comment: SOLVED PROBLEM!: I forgot to put accessURL in the credentials. Also oauthKey and oauthSecret are only for internal use according to the documentation.